# ORDER button (mysqli/PHP), different button same div

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, mysqli

This is my code which display database styled content.

```
<?php
include 'connect/con.php';

$query ="SELECT newsvid.id, newsvid.addName, newsvid.vidTitle, newsvid.url, newsvid.vidSD, newsvid.published, videoinformation.vidLD, videoinformation.vidYear, videoinformation.vidCity, videoinformation.vidZanr, videoinformation.vidZanr2, videoinformation.vidZanr3, videoinformation.vidQuality, videoinformation.vidTranslated, videoinformation.vidTime  FROM newsvid, videoinformation WHERE newsvid.id = videoinformation.id";
$order = isset($_GET['order']) ? $_GET['order'] : 'DESC';
$goodParam = array("ASC", "DESC");

if (in_array($order, $goodParam)) {
if($order == 'ASC'){
     $query .= " ORDER BY newsvid.id DESC"; 
}else{
     $query .= " ORDER BY newsvid.id ASC"; 
    }
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
echo "<div class=\"maincover \" data-role=\"scrollbox\" data-scroll=\"vertical\">";

echo "<div class=\"panel panel-default\">";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<div class=\"panel-heading\">";
echo '<div><a class="panel-title btn-block vidTitle" href="details.php?id='.$row['id'].'"><h5>'.$row['id'].' | '.$row['vidTitle'].'</h5></a></div>';
echo "</div>";

echo "<div class=\"panel-body\">";
echo "<div class=\"imgCover\"><img class=\"imageCover\"src=\"" . $row['url'] . "\"></div>";
echo "<div class=\"vidSD\">" . $row['vidSD'] . "</div>";
echo "<div class=\"vidDetails\"> 


<table>
<tr><td><strong> Years: </strong></td><td>" . $row['vidYear'] . "</td></tr>
<tr><td><strong> City: </strong></td><td>". $row['vidCity'] . "</td></tr>
<tr><td><strong> Zanr: </strong></td><td>". $row['vidZanr'] ." , ". $row['vidZanr2'] ." , ". $row['vidZanr3'] . "</td></tr>
<tr><td><strong> Quality: </strong></td><td>". $row['vidQuality'] . "</td></tr>
<tr><td><strong> Translated: </strong></td><td>". $row['vidTranslated'] . "</td></tr>
<tr><td><strong> Video time: </strong></td><td>". $row['vidTime'] .  "</td></tr>
</table> 
</div></div>";

echo " <div class=\"panel-footer\">";
echo '<h6><strong>Author: </strong><a href="../userPages/user.php?u='.$row['addName'].'">'.$row['addName'].'</a></h6>';
echo '<div><h6><strong>Published: </strong>' . $row['published'] . '</h6></div>'; 
echo "</div>";
}
echo "</div></div>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Question is:

I have this section:

```
if (in_array($order, $goodParam)) {
if($order == 'ASC'){
     $query .= " ORDER BY newsvid.id DESC"; 
}else{
     $query .= " ORDER BY newsvid.id ASC"; 
    }
```

And I'm using buttons in my Index page:

```
<a href="view.php?order=ASC">ASC</a> 
<a href="view.php?order=DESC">DESC</a>
```

Question is: currently I have that each button open **NEW**  page with ordered content. I need that every time you press different ordering button, ONLY content section (div) will change and not the whole website, so that the same style will stay.

I confused, the way that every ordering button pressed... style of the content will be the same and only ordering will change... I know how to open content in the same page BUT I do not want to copy design every time for each content page..when theoretically I need only change the last bit of query:

```
ORDER BY newsvid.id DESC
```

DESC or ASC or by DATA or NAME and e.t.c....

```
<body>
<div id="joe"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
// Fetch and display "content.htm" inside a DIV automatically as the page loads:
ajaxpagefetcher.load("joe", "content.htm", true)
</script>

<div id="bob"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
<!-- Fetch and display "sub/content2.htm" inside a DIV when a link is clicked on. Also load one .css file-->
<a href="javascript:ajaxpagefetcher.load('bob', 'sub/content2.htm', false, '', ['page.css'])">Load Content 2</a>
</script>

</body>
```

This is what I do not want to do.... or DO but change only type of ordering and not full content...

Comment: You need to implement asynchronous request using `ajax`. Lots of great tutorials around the internet. Another solution would be to use `javascript` and/or `jquery` to sort that table when button is clicked, or ready solutions such as `datatables`.

Comment: You do realize that `ASC` is the default sort order, and you could save yourself the trouble for having logic to handle that.

Comment: I done ASC and DESC just for testing, I'm not sure how exactly do it... in this case...

Comment: jQuery or javascript will be able to handle large datasets while an exclusively browser based datastore will not. Best to use an ajax approach eg with jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you have it, everytime you click the ASC or DESC button, the same page will refresh and display all the information again.

What you might be looking for is a web technology called Ajax. It's basically javascript with some api calls to refresh and load certain parts of a webpage without sending a whole server request to reload the whole html on a page again.

Other than that, there is no way to refresh / load certains parts of a page without reloading the whole page again.

Comment: I confused, the way that every ordering button pressed styles of the content will be the same and only ordering will change... I know how to open content in the same page BUT I do not want to copy design every time for each content page...

Answer (score 1):

"Question is: currently I have that each button open NEW page with ordered content. I need that every time you press different ordering button, ONLY content section (div) will change and not the whole website, so that the same style will stay."

To change just the content of the div and reload a new page, you need to use some jQuery or other javascript to update the DOM with new data on button ( actually link) click.

Answer (score 0):

If i would have faced the similar problem i had done it using **"form method"** of HTML since i don't know ajax currently.

```
  <?php
  if(isset($_POST['ASC']))   /* if user have clicked ASC button ,do this */
  {
     $query .= " ORDER BY newsvid.id ASC";
     echo "<div class='ur_div'>" . display() . "</div>";
  }
  if(isset($_POST['DESC']))   /* if user have clicked DESC button ,do this */
  {
     $query .= " ORDER BY newsvid.id DESC";
     echo "<div class='ur_div'>" . display() . "</div>";
  }

   echo "<form method='post' action='SamePage.php'>";
   echo "<input type='submit' name='ASC' value='ASC'>";
   echo "</form>";

   echo "<form method='post' action='SamePage.php'>";
   echo "<input type='submit' name='DESC' value='DESC'>";
   echo "</form>";
   ?>
```